# GRPC generated pb.go file has unresolved types

Tags: go, grpc

I have an issue with generating pb.go files.

This is my authorizationsvc.proto file:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package pb;

option go_package = "../authorization";

service Authorization {
  rpc Register(RegisterRequest) returns (RegisterReply) {}
}

message User {
  string username = 1;
  string password = 2;
  string email = 3;
}

message RegisterRequest {
  User user = 1;
}

message RegisterReply {
  string userID = 1;
  string error = 2;
}
```

pb-compile.sh

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh


REPO_ROOT="${REPO_ROOT:-$(cd "$(dirname "$0")/../.." && pwd)}"
PB_PATH="${REPO_ROOT}/api/v1/pb/authorization"
PROTO_FILE=${1:-"authorizationsvc.proto"}

echo "Generating pb files for ${PROTO_FILE} service"
protoc -I="${PB_PATH}" --go-grpc_out="${PB_PATH}" "${PB_PATH}/${PROTO_FILE}"
```

and the generated authorizationsvc_grpc.pb.go

```golang
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go-grpc. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
// - protoc-gen-go-grpc v1.2.0
// - protoc             v3.19.3
// source: authorizationsvc.proto

package authorization

import (
    context "context"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
    codes "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    status "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the grpc package it is being compiled against.
// Requires gRPC-Go v1.32.0 or later.
const _ = grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion7

// AuthorizationClient is the client API for Authorization service.
//
// For semantics around ctx use and closing/ending streaming RPCs, please refer to https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/?tab=doc#ClientConn.NewStream.
type AuthorizationClient interface {
    Register(ctx context.Context, in *RegisterRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*RegisterReply, error)
}
```

My initial concern is that RegisterRequest and RegisterReply are unresolved types and Goland is showing an error.

Comment: You're only generating go-grpc code; the messages are normal protobufs, not grpc. You also need to specify `--go_out=`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt --go_out is deprecated it tells me, and we should use --go-grpc_out instead

Comment: @Laterneman, specify both `--go_out` and `--go-grpc_out` args.